# make equation from mathml which is computable by python

Tags: javascript, python, output, mathml

Part of my projects deals with getting equation from mathml which can be send to  python.The python should easily handle the equation .The mathml is given below .The expected python equation is also given below.What modification should be given to this  javascript to get that..

```
    var mList = ['pow', 'sin', 'cos', 'tan', 'sqrt', 'π'];

    function getDOM(xmlstring) {
        parser=new DOMParser();
        return parser.parseFromString(xmlstring, "text/xml");
    }
    function remove_tags(node) {
        var result = "";
        var nodes = node.childNodes;
        var tagName = node.tagName;
        if (!nodes.length) {
            /*if(mList.indexOf(node.nodeValue) != -1 ) {
                result += 'math.'
            }*/
            if (node.nodeValue == "π") result += "pi";
            else if (node.nodeValue == " ") result += "";
            else result += node.nodeValue;
        } else if (tagName == "mfrac") {
            result += "("+remove_tags(nodes[0])+")/("+remove_tags(nodes[1])+")";
        } else if (tagName == "msup") {
            result += "power(("+remove_tags(nodes[0])+"),("+remove_tags(nodes[1])+"))";

        } else for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
            result += remove_tags(nodes[i]);
        }
        if (tagName == "mfenced") result = "("+result+")";
        if (tagName == "msqrt") result = "sqrt("+result+")";

        return result;
    }
    function stringifyMathML(mml) {
       xmlDoc = getDOM(mml);  
       return remove_tags(xmlDoc.documentElement);
    }
```

the equation [image]

mml="sin2x+cos2x+sin4x+3";
    u=stringifyMathML(mml);
     alert(u)

the output is

```
 power((sin),(2))(x)+power((cos),(2))(x)+sin(4x+3)
```

but the ouput should be

```
  power(sin(x),2)+power(cos(x),2)+sin(4*x+3)
```

the mathml provided is ::-

```
"<math><msup><mi>sin</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mfenced><mi>x</mi></mfenced><mo>+</mo><msup><mi>cos</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mfenced><mi>x</mi></mfenced><mo>+</mo><mi>sin</mi><mfenced><mrow><mn>4</mn><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>3</mn></mrow></mfenced></math>"
```

the following program can be seen in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/user1989/g0ca42m2/2/
What change should be made in the javascript to get the expected output

Answer (score 2):

Your "problem" come from your "blind" parsing.

Your first output is right. msup sin 2 mfenced x gives you sin²(x) -> power(sin,2)(x).

In order to rendering power(sin(x),2) you have to fetch for the next node (as a "lookahead") before making your translation. A quick fix should be to add a "nextNode" argument (which may be null) and also base your parsing on it.

Comment: Can you be more specific? If you can post as an answer, it will be very helpful!!

Comment: Problwm supposed to be in `else if (tagName == "mfrac") {
        result += "("+remove_tags(nodes[0])+")/("+remove_tags(nodes[1])+")";
    }`

Comment: It can be quite hard to properly parse your string. Are you trying have a full MathML support or just the example you gave ? You should search about parser LR / LL / LALR just to have an idea of the complexity. Maybe you should look for a library written in javascript or python to match your need.

Comment: B can you suggest a library buddy it will be more helpful. I have researched a lot but not able to spot one!!